# Execute function on each item click, but also once on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with boxes and I want a function to run on each box click. Additionally, I want the function to run ONCE on page load.

(The idea is that the function "updates the state", and I want to update on each click, but also on page load - to initialize the state, so to speak.)

Normally, I do this like so:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    // do something
}).first().click();
```

So I attach the handler to each `.box` click event, and then I get the first `.box` element and trigger the click event on it.

This approach works, but it feels kind-of clumsy. How do you tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has [`triggerHandler()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/), which offers a number of advantages that may be desired for your code.

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    // do something
}).triggerHandler('click');
```

> **From the docs:**
>
> - The `.triggerHandler()` method does not cause the default behavior of an event to occur (such as a form submission).
> - While `.trigger()` will operate on all elements matched by the jQuery object, `.triggerHandler()` *only affects the first matched element*.
> - Events created with `.triggerHandler()` do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly, they do nothing.
> - Instead of returning the jQuery object (to allow chaining), `.triggerHandler()` returns whatever value was returned by the last handler it caused to be executed. If no handlers are triggered, it returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would probably do it.

```
(function(){
    var foo = function(){
              // stuff
           }
    $('.box').click(foo);
    foo();
})();
```

Calls foo when it initializes and adds it to the click.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could also work :

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.box').click(function() {
        $(this).val("Value"); //Your function here
    });

    $('.box').each(function() {
      $(this).val("Ready"); //Your function here
    });    
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S2Y4F/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
function hello() {
    //Here goes your update function
    alert('world');
}

$('.box').click(hello);
hello();
```